# Load JSON data in my initital state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to learn React.js but I have some difficulties to load data from my server with redux. For the moment my global state is loaded with static json like this:

My store.js

```
import ...

// Load my static json data
import tickets from '../data/tickets.js'
import interventions from '../data/interventions.js'

const defaultState = {
  tickets,
  interventions
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState);
export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
export default store;
```

My application works perfectly. Now I want to fill my components with the data returned from my node.js server. However I have no idea how to corretly do it.

I have to fill my defaultState only once ? After the reducers will change the values ?

Is isomorphic-fetch is a good way to call a url from my server ? (I use react-router on my client)

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/courses/reactjsprogrambundle

Comment: Thanks now give me 645 dollars.

Comment: Hahaha... put it through on company expenses. There's lots to learn. Well worth the investment.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to do this on client side you would be asynchronous.

On your entry point, where you are importing the store, you can fetch your data then dispatch an action that will init your tickets or interventions.

You can also use [redux-async-connect](https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect) to give your app all required data  before it's will be mounted, this can be use also on server rendering side